# How to run CPU intensive parallel tasks with Vert.X in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, node.js, asynchronous, vert.x

I want to run  run CPU intensive parallel tasks in Java, but to avoid the complicated debugging of race conditions, I decided to try an **asynchronous program model**. I have experience with Node.JS, I know how asynchronous stuff works and I understand the event loop. I think I don't understand the [Worker Verticles in Vert.x](http://vertx.io/manual.html#worker-verticles) .

Imagine the following Java code that has 3 CPU intensive processes (method slowProcess()).

- How can I compute a, b and c parallelly?
- Is the asynchronous model suitable for this, or should I use normal thread?
- Is the asynchronous model only made for I/O operations?

  ```
  public class Race {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
      long a=0, b=0, c=0;

      System.out.print("starting ... ");

      //start the race
      // these 3 things should run in parallel
      a = slowProcess(a);
      b = slowProcess(b);
      c = slowProcess(c);

      // this should run after the 3 processes are finished
      long result =evaluate (a,b,c);

      System.out.print("finished : "+result);

  }

  private static long evaluate(long a, long b, long c) {
      return a+b+c;
  }

  private static long slowProcess(long value) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 200000; j++)
      for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
      {
          value++;            
      }
      return value;
  }
  }
  ```

**Update/note**: This is a simplified example. For these 3 processes and the simple result handling, Thread joining would be better. The real problem is more complex. I'm only wondering if someone can translate this code into an asynchronised version, or tell me why it should not be done with high CPU load processes, since they block the event queue (I think).

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

1. create 3 worker verticles for slow process and 1 main verticle for firing process and
   collecting all results from workers created just now.
2. create event buses between these verticles.

Then the whole picture is:

1. main verticle sends messages including input to those worker (in your example, it is sending a, b, c to worker, also main verticle should register a handler for return message from workers.)
2. a worker gets an input and returns result to main verticle via its event bus
3. main verticle waits for the results from worker, if all results are returned, then it could do its job, else it can just save the result to its local cache and return.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For given use case, where there are only 3 long-runnung processes, threads are the best choice. Just wrap `slowProcess` in a class which implements Runnable and saves result inside. Start threads, wait them with Thread.join(), and extract results.

Asynchronous model is good not only for I/O operations, but for any situation with many short tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually that is a simplified example. There are not just 3 processes, there are between 10 and 20 and there are also several small steps, that rely partly on previous results. I only put a siple example in so I would understand it, if someone translates it to Vert.X (or another event queue implementation) for me. I will update the question, to make that clearer.

Comment: there are many concepts and implementations of asynchronous model. Vert.x is rather rich and complex: it supports clustering and common event bus. If you need not clustering, and medium sized execution graph, where nodes can have direct references to each other, you better use simpler framework. Describe your task in more detail, so that people can suggest more suitable framework.

Answer (score 0):

many MQ patterns (,specifically zeromq which is broke-less) are reusables inside vertx because they share similar ideas, like pubsub and req/rep communication, now,inside zeromq you can use a pattern named ventilator which allow archive parallel computation in a pretty simple way

you could read about it here
http://taotetek.net/2011/02/02/python-multiprocessing-with-zeromq/
[http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:taskvent](http://zguide.zeromq.org/java%3ataskvent)

although I haven't so much experience with vertx I'm pretty sure than you can apply this pattern inside vertx using verticles